# Rails 3: HEROKU staging and production repo managment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've setup my app to run on Heroku with a staging and production environment as according to their documents. http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

It seems pretty straightforward to manage with the staging app, push entire deployments or new branches up to test in staging. What I wonder is how to manage the production version.

How do I keep my production up and running when deploying new code? Do I pull in the changes from staging or do I redeploy the entire app with the changes merged in?

Secondly, how do I manage and keep my database intact during all of this? I'm used to running locally where if you do a new deploy and a new rake :db:migrate, you lose all your database data. How is this done in production to not lose your records?

Thanks you and ANY other tips regarding heroku management is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you make changes locally, including migrations or whatever. Before pushing your changes to your production app, push changes to your staging app to double-check things are okay.

If you added migrations in your changes, be sure to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to migrate your staging database. Running rake db:migrate should *not* destroy any data so long as your migration is proper - i.e. no weird tampering with data, just the standard addition/renaming/etc. of columns or introducing new tables. (Obviously if you drop a table in a migration it'll be gone.)

Then, if everything is okay with your staging app, push changes to your production, and again run `heroku run rake db:migrate` if you had any new migrations. If things are not okay, run `heroku help` to get a list of commands you can use - particularly ones with regard to releases so you can revert back to a previous release. Also `heroku logs` is really useful, and `heroku console` (actual command might be slightly different), though when you start a console, be really careful not to tamper with data too much.

With Heroku, there's no deploy command needed - right when you git push, your updated code is there. No "cap deploy" with capistrano, if you've used that before.

Hope this helps.